# Run MySQL Query From Button Click

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, mysql

How can I run a `MySQL` query from the `onclick` event of an `HTML` button on my site?

For example if my button is created like so, how could I use this to run a `MySQL` query titled AddInfo

```
<p><button type="button">Run A SQL Stored Procedure</button></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **PHP** for that. Here's an example :

```
<html>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
</html>
```

and then

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//execute mysql query
}
```

Use [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer) to include **PHP** scripts inside a custom HTML module.

### EDIT :

> **How to use Sourcerer ?**

- After the plugin is installed, a button (**CODE**) is added below the
  **WYSIWYG** editor :

[image]

- Clicking on **Code** button opens a pop-up, enter your code between 
  **{source}** and **{/source}** tags like this:

[image]

- Hit the green **Insert button** to add this code to your Article or
  Custom HTML module :)

Comment: You don't need to include html tags ;) they already exist in the template

Comment: I have installed this extension, how to use it in my article so that I can use the syntax?  Does Joomla auto-detect that the extension is installed and can use PHP?

Comment: @NadineSmithJonesPicard Answer updated with Sourcerer tutorial ;)